# TeamCity 4.5 not recognizing trycatch element in nant script

Tags: nant, teamcity, try-catch, build-script

Our team recently upgraded to TeamCity 4.5.4 but we're having trouble with TeamCity running our nant build scripts.

We now get an error message saying: `Invalid element <trycatch>. Unknown task or datatype.`

We haven't changed our build script during or after the upgrade so I'm wondering what, if any, change do we need to make to get this working again.

The part of the script that is causing problems is as follows:

```
<trycatch>
  <try>
<ncover>
       <snip>this does ncover stuff</snip>
</ncover>
  </try>
  <catch property="failure">
   <echo message="At least one test failed: ${failure}"/>
       <property name="fail.message" value="${failure}"/>
       <property name="test.failed" value="true"/>
  </catch>
</trycatch>
```

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the trycatch task is part of NantContrib. It is possible that NantContrib isn't included with team city anymore. Or your script needs an update reference to nantcontrib. Just a thought.